# Slide animation from bottom and up between activities

Tags: android, android-animation

I successfully created sliding animation between activities, where the new activity slides from the bottom and up. The problem: When sliding up, it "pushes" the old activity outside to take its space. I would like to create animation that doesn't move the old activity but just slides from bottom and up on top of the old activity, while the old activity stands still.

**slide_in_up.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:fromYDelta="100%p"
        android:toYDelta="0" />
</set>
```

**slide_out_down.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="-100%p" />
</set>
```

function to start the new activity with a slide:

```
override fun startEditProfile() {
    startActivity(EditProfileActivity.newIntent(this))
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.slide_out_down)
}
```

Is it possible to make the new activity slide from bottom to top while the old activity isn't moving?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see the source code comment about the `overridePendingTransition` two params:

> ```
>  @param enterAnim A resource ID of the animation resource to use for
>  the incoming activity.  Use 0 for no animation.
>  @param exitAnim A resource ID of the animation resource to use for
>  the outgoing activity.  Use 0 for no animation.
> ```

so if you want the exit(old) activity doesn't move, change the exit animation to that

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

or set 0 for no animaton